# Page access not retrievable for LWC community

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata, experience-cloud, public

When setting the "Page access" to either "Public" or "Require Login", it's not retrieved in the metadata by using the "sfdx force:source:pull" command. I would somehow expect it to be part of the page view JSON file.

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: actually it is in the route json

Comment: `"pageAccess" : "Public",`

Comment: Did not find the property in the route json file. Tried to add it manually and deploy to the org but received the following error: "The PageAccess property of .../routes/home.json can't be changed during deployment. Update your file and try again."